# how change value of some DataTable columns and show them in report by stimulsoft

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I have some information in a **DataTable** and want show them in report.
I use **stimulsoft** for reporting.

now I want change value of some columns and show changed value in report.

this is my code:

```
SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter sqladap = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sqlcom.Connection = main.sqlcon;
sqladap.SelectCommand = sqlcom;

sqlcom.CommandText = "select  * from table ...";
sqladap.Fill(dt);

dt.TableName = "userhusband";
StiReport rpt = new StiReport();
rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\data\Report.mrt");
rpt.RegData(dt);
rpt.Dictionary.Synchronize();

rpt.Show();
```

now how change value of some columns and show in report ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your report before binding again to it!

Just use `rpt.Reset()` in top of your report code. and in asp.net use `StiWebViewer1.ResetReport()` (assuming `StiWebViewer1` is the element in your asp page).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the dt value like below then show it in your report

```
  for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      dt.Rows[i][columnNumber] = "newValue"; }
    }
```

Comment: I used this way before but didnt work!  I attached this **datatable** to a **datagridview**. when I change column values by this way values chenges in **datagridview** but dont change in **report** !!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the DataTable and register it in the report again.